# Custom Grails exception handling

Tags: java, grails, exception, groovy

Following an [example with custom exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349957/grails-common-exception-handling-in-grails-1-1) in Grails, I came to the following code:

```
exceptionHandler.exceptionMappings = [
    'my.project.AccessDeniedException': '/accessDenied',
    'my.project.NoSessionException' : '/accessDenied',
    'java.lang.Exception': '/errorProduction'
]
```

This works fine for the first two types of exceptions, but all other exceptions, like [GroovyPagesException](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/exceptions/GroovyPagesException.html), are not handled by Grails anymore, they are handled by the servlet container.

How can I handle all exceptions with Grails (1.3)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

UrlMappings.groovy:

```
"500"(controller: 'errors', action: 'handle')
```

And the controller:

```
class ErrorsController {

    def handle = {
        def exception = request.exception.cause.class
        if(exception == my.project.NoSessionException ||
               exception == my.project.AccessDeniedException)
            render(view: '/accessDenied')
        else
            render(view: '/errorProduction')
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want to surface a 500 error page for such errors?  I've used the UrlMappings configuration to override certain kinds of errors with custom pages.

```
  "500"(controller: "error", action: "cartGone", exception: CartGoneException)
```

Curious what the requirement is here?

Comment: I tried it this way, but it all exceptions are handled by the java.lang.Exception handler then.